non-zero prime ideals in the ring of algebraic integers
It is said that:

If $P$ is a nonzero prime ideal in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$ then $P\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $\alpha\in P$, then the constant term of the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is then an element in $P\cap\mathbb{Z}$, which shows that $P\cap\mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$ is also a nonzero prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $m(x)=x^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}\cdots+a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\alpha_1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_d$ be the remaining roots of $m(x)$, then $a_0=(-1)^d\left(\prod_{i=2}^d\alpha_i\right)\alpha_1$. So to prove $a_0\in P$ it suffices to show that $\left(\prod_{i=2}^d\alpha_i\right)\in\mathcal{O}_K$, i.e., showing that $a_0/\alpha_1$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. But I can not finish this unless suppose that $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ so that the roots $\alpha_i$ all lie in $K$ and hence lie in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then so does their product $\left(\prod_{i=2}^d\alpha_i\right)$.
Is there a proof of $\left(\prod_{i=2}^d\alpha_i\right)\in\mathcal{O}_K$ without assuming that $K$ is Galois?

If $K$ is Galois, then every conjugates of $\alpha$ is again in $K$, and more precisely in $\mathcal{O}_K$, as they are roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ which has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. 
Hence, in a Galois extension, the conjugates of an integer are again integers. 
So if $K$ is not Galois, take $L=K^{\textrm{gal}}$ the Galois closure of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, you know that $\prod_{i=2}^d \alpha_i$ is in $\mathcal{O}_L$. Thus it is an algebraic integer, and it is also in $K$ as it is equal to $\frac{ \pm a_0}{\alpha} \in K$. Hence $\prod_{i=2}^d \alpha_i \in\mathcal{O}_K$. 

Proving that $a_0$ is in $P$ can be made simpler. Indeed, we have $0=\alpha^d + \dots + a_1 \alpha + a_0 \in P$. As $\alpha\in P$, you get $a_0\in P$.

Thanks very much!

No problem ! Can you valid the answer, so that the topic will be visible as answered ? thanks

Do you mean that click the "✓"? If so, I have done.
